# openode.io respones 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, deployment

My site in opennode.io http://ridezonebd.us.openode.io/ was running fine for 3 days. But today I am getting 502 Bad Gateway when trying to browse.

Comment: Maybe you should contact their support then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a 502 HTTP code when your server is no more accessible (either if it has crashed or was stopped). In your case it is due to a lack of credit - in this case we shutdown the running instance.